# Installing Theme for magento 1.9.0 pagayo

Tags: theme, install

Uploaded the files, saw it in design, put it as active today.  Cleared the cache and it didn't show, then disable the cache and it still pointing to /default vs. pt003

Comment: can you brielf tell me the path of folder struture of your theme.is it like  app/design/frontend/yourpackageneme/yourthemename or app/design/frontend/default/yourthemename ?

Comment: /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/pt003

Comment: and you are using magento version 1.9 ?

Comment: yes version 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Go to System > Configuration > Design > Pacage and System > Configuration > Design > Package

[image]

and change some configurations.like replave yourtheme from the image with the pt003.

then save and clear cache and check frontend.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested and my pacakge and themes are identical (except yourtheme is replaced with pt003) and I've cleared all of the cache under "system->Cache management" still seeing the default skin.

Comment: as you comment above your folder structure.it is clear that default is your package name and pt003 is your theme name

Comment: Yes, that is how I have it setup.  I did try putting my package as "pt003" but it gave an error that that package did not exist

Comment: yes correct.please put your package name as default and just replace yourtheme word with pt003

Comment: http://www.jewelersnation.com/screen1.png

Settings

Comment: Any ideas why it's not showing with those settings?